# Problema com Selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Estou tentando aprender o Selenium WebDriver por conta própria, mas estou tendo dificuldades.

Alguns comandos não estão funcionando no Eclipse.

Por exemplo, para o comando "`Import org.openqa.selenium.webdriver`" aparece a mensagem:

> The import org.junit.selenium cannot be resolved

Podem me ajudar?

Answer (score -1):

Acredito que você apenas tenha digitado errado. Tente com as iniciais de "webdriver" em maiúsculo:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
```